# Past simple and pluperfect with “before”

Tags: conjunctions, past-perfect, sequence-of-tenses

Which of the following is correct?

1. “I had learned to sing before I learned to dance.”
2. “I learned to sing before I had learned to dance.”
3. “I learned to sing before I learned to dance.”

I think only the first should be correct as the “before” implies that the learning to sing happened further back in the past than the learning to dance, and so needs to be put in pluperfect. However, as an English near-native speaker, the other options also don’t “sound wrong” to me.

Comment: By what criteria are you judging “correctness”?

Comment: They don't sound wrong because they are not. You choose the tense that fits what you want to say.

Comment: I'm sure that this is a duplicate (Is logical tense sequencing involving the past perfect (pluperfect) always mandatory?) Here is an answer from a comment by [Shoe](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/534631/problem-with-backshift-past-simple-to-past-perfect): << Swan in _Practical English Usage_ (page 251) states in the section reporting past tenses: "...past perfect tenses are not always used, especially if the time relationships are clear without a change from past to past perfect."  Here, the 'before' is totally adequate to correctly sequence the events. (3) is fine. (1) is ...

Comment: not incorrect, and may be a better choice in certain contexts, but is ponderous in a standalone sentence. I'm actually not sure about (2), so I'd avoid it. It may be grammatical, but involves an unusual use of the past perfect.

Comment: There's also "I had learned to sing before I had learned to dance." Another perfectly correct sentence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you very much, what I was trying to ask was indeed a duplicate of the question you linked to!